# 404 exception (IIS)

Tags: iis, azure

I'm trying to handle 404 error under IIS (and Azure) but the code below does not work.
On the localhost this works well.
What should I do to fix this problem?

from httpmodule

```
protected void Application_Error(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;
    Exception ex = application.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    if (ex != null && ex is HttpException)
    {
        var httpEx = ex as HttpException;
        if (httpEx != null && httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            application.Response.Redirect(BXSite.Current.GetUrl("/404/"));
            application.Server.ClearError();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i belive this link will guide you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059009/enable-custom-errors-in-azure

Comment: What do you mean by not work? Do you see any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added "false" to the second parameter of Redirect function and redirect began works right.
Like this:
application.Response.Redirect("/404/",false).