# Copying files to a specific IIS directory using startup cmd in Azure

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure

I want to create a startup cmd task in an Azure web role to copy a specific file into the `inetpub\custerr\en-US` directory before the role starts. Ideally, I'd like to be able to override the default error response html files. The overriding file will be stored inside the VS solution for the web role.

The following is a screenshot from IIS Manager's Error Pages window.

[image]

I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I suppose `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr\en-US` should be the path to destination. How do I get the absolute/relative path to the file to be copied? I was thinking of adding it under the web role project and setting its Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always. What will the code in the startup cmd look like?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way of doing the same, thought it might help you.
Check this: [Enable custom errors in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059009/enable-custom-errors-in-azure)

Comment: How does this work for Web API? I see the example is for MVC. Not sure if a route can be specified instead of a URL for the path variable in <error />.

Comment: Probably, check this query & the link mentioned in the query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858925/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-error-pages-with-mvc4-site-but-not-web-api